# Apache FOP, Unicode. Text is not searchable

Tags: apache, pdf, unicode, apache-fop

I've got a problem with some legacy Java code that renders PDF files.

We're using Apache FOP:

```
Implementation-Title: Fop
Implementation-Version: 0.20.5 
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation (http://xml.apache.org/fop/)
```

With options set to:

```
<configuration>
  <fonts>
   <font metrics-file="arialuni.xml" 
        embed-file="ARIALUNI.TTF" kerning="yes">            
    <font-triplet name="arialuni" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>
 </fonts>
</configuration>
```

The .pdf is rendered correctly, there is one big problem though:
I'm not able to search text in such file and if I'll try to copy-paste this text - I'll get a lot of symbols-boxes.(□)

As I've understood - the arialuni.ttf (unicode version of arial, i suppose) causes this troubles. Is there some known solutions? Is it possible to fix that with font configuration?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm not allowed to switch to any other pdf-rendering library, or upgrade an existing one.

Edit #1

Thank you all for your answers. We'll probably refuse from Unicode support for now and will upgrade to the 1.0 version later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to slap your boss and get him to approve some time for an upgrade to Apache FOP 1.0 or later. Seriously.

The only alternative is to try "-enc ansi" as parameter to the "TTFReader" application when you generate the XML font metrics file. That will cause FOP 0.20.5 to use WinAnsi encoding instead of CID encoding. The downside: you'll be restricted to the WinAnsi 8bit encoding. You don't get the whole Unicode set.

Comment: Jeremias, thank you for reply. Is it true, that an upgrade will solve the problem with unicode? Probably I'll convince the management to do an upgrade, but a lot of code should be rewritten in this case.

Comment: Yes, Apache FOP 1.0 can generate the necessary PDF structures (ToUnicode CMap) for CID fonts. Alternatively, it also supports extended single-byte support (encoding-mode="single-byte") which also has no text extraction problems. This extended single-byte support goes farther than that of 0.20.5. You're no longer restricted to 255 characters in single-byte mode (FOP generates multiple single-byte encodings).

Comment: Adding encoding-mode="single-byte" to the fonts in the fop configuration does help. Tested with FOP 2.2. Without the encoding-mode, I was not able to copy or search the text. After adding encoding-mode="single-byte" I was.

Answer (score 0):

> PS: I'm not allowed to switch to any other pdf-rendering library, or upgrade an existing one.

If you can't use "arial.ttf", then you're almost certainly doomed.  There's a bug in the way that version of FOP is embedding...

HEY!  It's entirely possible that your font isn't embedded at all:

From the [Apache FOP fonts](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/fonts.html#register) page:

```
<fonts>
  <!-- register a particular font -->
  <font metrics-url="file:///C:/myfonts/FTL_____.xml" kerning="yes"
      embed-url="file:///C:/myfonts/FTL_____.pfb">
     <font-triplet name="FrutigerLight" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>
</fonts>
```

1. Sadly, I don't see any mention of specifying a particular encoding anywhere in those docs.
2. You're using "embed-file" not "embed-url="file:///".  I suspect that's your problem.

Comment: embed-file for 0.20.5 is quite ok. embed-url was introduced after 0.90. The encoding is implicit and is an 8-bit WinAnsi encoding for Type 1 fonts. For TrueType font 0.20.5 already did CID subset encoding (i.e. no particular encoding). The problem is that PDFs constructed with FOP 0.20.5 lack additional information (ToUnicode CMap) for PDF Readers to reconstruct the actual text.